# Embedding another Window as a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, allegro

I'm currently working on a project that uses Allegro for rendering, input, etc. However I would like to add a GUI to my project using something like Qt. The problem is that Allegro does not support using a Window not created by allegro for rendering/input, it needs to create the window itself. I was thinking of using Qt to make the UI, and then creating a window normally using allegro, and then somehow embedding the allegro window into the Qt application.

Allegro provides the `HWND` handle to the window its using. Is there anyway to embed the allegro window into a Qt ui using its `HWND` handle?

Comment: Which target platforms do you want to support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [`QWinHost`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/qtwinmigrate/qwinhost.html) class from the Qt/MFC Migration Framework. The code is 3-clause BSD licensed. You only need two files: `qwinhost.h` and `qwinhost.cpp`, available [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/source/80592b0e7145fb876ea0e84a6e3dadfd5f7481b6%3aqtwinmigrate/src).

It does exactly what you need, and works on both Qt 4 and 5.